# Undefined Reference to a function

Tags: c++, c, linux, undefined-reference

I'm using Linux and I have the following files:

```
main.c, main.h
fileA.c, fileA.h
fileB.cpp, fileB.h
```

The function `F1()` is declared in `fileB.h` and defined in `fileB.cpp`. I need to use the function in `fileA.c`, and so I declared the function as

```
extern void F1();
```

in `fileA.c`.

However, during compilation, I got the error

```
fileA.c: (.text+0x2b7): undefined reference to `F1'
```

What is wrong?

Thank you.

ETA: Thanks to the answers I've received, I now have the following:

In fileA.h, I have

```
#include fileB.h
#include main.h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
#endif
void F1();
```

In fileA.c, I have

```
#include fileA.h
```

In fileB.h, I have

```
extern "C" void F1();
```

In fileB.cpp, I have

```
#include "fileB.h"

extern "C" void F1()
{ }
```

However, I now have the error

```
fileB.h: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're really compiling `fileA.c` as C, not C++, then you need to make sure that the function has the proper, C-compatible linkage.

You can do this with a special case of the `extern` keyword. Both at declaration and definition:

```
extern "C" void F1();
extern "C" void F1() {}
```

Otherwise the C linker will be looking for a function that only really exists with some mangled C++ name, and an unsupported calling convention. :)

Unfortunately, whilst this is what you have to do in C++, [the syntax isn't valid in C](http://www.ideone.com/EB3Iz). You must make the `extern` visible only to the C++ code.

So, with some preprocessor magic:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void F1();
```

Not entirely pretty, but it's the price you pay for sharing a header between code of two languages.

Comment: So now I have extern "C" void F1(); and extern "C" void F1() {} in my fileB.h and fileB.cpp respectively, and also extern "C" void F1(); in fileA.c. But during compilation, I get the errors "fileB.h: error: expected identifier or "(" before string constant", "fileA.c: error: expected identifier or "(" before string constant", and also "fileA.c: warning: implicit declaration of function "F1"."

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm still getting some errors. See my edit of my original entry.

Comment: @Rayne: It's `__cplusplus`, not `__cpluplus`. And the problem is: your C can see the function declaration twice. One from the header (where you haven't used the macro: this is _the_ place you should be doing it, as this is the code that's shared between languages), and one from `fileA.c`, where you shouldn't be writing a declaration at all.

Comment: @Tomalak: I've made the changes (please see edit in original entry), but am still getting the "expected identifier" error. I don't have the "implicit declaration" error anymore.

Comment: @Rayne: Why does `fileB.h` declare the header? Your C code can _still_ see a line of `extern "C"`. Think about what includes go where. You should declare the function _in **one** header_ and define it _in **one** source file_. The header can be included in many places, including (thanks to our macro trick) in a C source file.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I can finally compile and link the program now.

Answer (score 5):

To be able to call a c++ function from c source code you neeed to give the appropriate `linkage specification`.

The format for specifying linkage specification is

```
extern "type_of_Linkage" <function_name>
```

So in your case, you should be using:

```
extern "C" void F1();
```

Answer (score 4):

perhaps, use

```
extern "C" void F1();
```

Answer (score 2):

fileA.c can't include fileB.h (via fileA.h) because the C compiler doesn't know what extern "C" means, so it complains that it sees an identifier before a string. don't try to include fileB.h in fileA.c or fileA.h. its not needed

Answer (score -1):

fileA.c needs to also include fileA.h I believe.

Comment: Inclusion failure gives declaration errors at compile-time, not definition errors at link-time.