# undefined reference to function called 'full_adder(BIT A, BIT B, BIT Ci, BIT *Co)'

Tags: c, undefined-reference

I am a CS student learning how to program in C. I have 3 files and a Makefile. I have

> logic.c logic.h main.c

the top of logic.c is:

```
 #include "logic.h" 
//use this function in 4 bit adder 
//BIT full_adder(BIT A, BIT B, BIT Ci, BIT *Co);
int adder(int O1, int O2,  BIT carryIn, BIT *carryOut){
printf("in adder");
return 0x0;
}


BIT full_adder(BIT A, BIT B, BIT Ci, BIT *Co){ 
BIT S = FALSE; 
    //implementation of if else's based on Truth Table <br>
    if((A==FALSE)&&(B==FALSE)&&(Ci==FALSE)){ 
        S=FALSE; 
        *Co = FALSE; 
    } <br>
    return S; 
}
```

the top of main.c is:

```
 #include "logic.h"
BIT full_adder(BIT A, BIT B, BIT Ci, BIT *Co);
```

in main.c I have my main function, at the bottom of main function I have :

```
 assert((full_adder(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,&Co)==FALSE) && (Co==FALSE));
        adder(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,&Co2);   
    return 0;
```

I am getting the error:

```
 main.o: In function 'main': main.c:158: undefined referenceto 'full_adder' 

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status <br>
make: *** [pa3] Error 1 <br>
./bscript: line 3: pa3: command not found
```

This is homework, but I have spent a good deal of time on this problem and am looking for some help. I have the correct return type for adder, full_adder, and I declare the function in the top of both logic.c and main.c.

The questions that did not answer my question were:

- [Undefined Reference to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423340/undefined-reference-to-a-function)
- ["Undefined reference to function" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277344/undefined-reference-to-function-error)

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
logic.c is getting compiled and it does create a logic.o file.

EDIT: my prof says that I cannot edit logic.h

EDIT: makefile:

```
# Makefile template for CS 270 (specialized for PA3) 

# List of files
C_SRCS      = main.c logic.c
C_OBJS      = main.o logic.o
C_HEADERS   = logic.h
OBJS        = ${C_OBJS} 
EXE         = pa3 

# Compiler and loader commands and flags
GCC         = gcc
GCC_FLAGS   = -g -std=c99 -Wall -O0 -c
LD_FLAGS    = -g -std=c99 -Wall -O0
# Target is the executable
pa3 : $(OBJS)
    @echo "Linking all object modules ..."
    $(GCC) $(LD_FLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(EXE)
    @echo ""
# Recompile C objects if headers change
${C_OBJS}:      ${C_HEADERS}
# Compile .c files to .o files
.c.o:
    @echo "Compiling each C source file separately ..."
    $(GCC) $(GCC_FLAGS) $<
    @echo ""

# Clean up the directory
clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up project directory ..."
    rm -f *.o $(EXE) core a.out
    @echo ""
```

EDIT: I compile my code with the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
make
pa3
```

Comment: I'm assuming they'll all want you to post the makefile

Comment: Are you actually implementing `full_adder`?

Comment: please show how you compile your code? show your makefile?

Comment: @H2CO3 I think you mean 'am I making a logical representation of a full adder?' Yes. Many not gates and and gates and ultimately I will be making a 4 bit adder.

Comment: At least my answer makes no changes to the `logic.h` file. I just included a trimmed down version of it to show where things should go, nothing more. Have you tried the suggested change to `logic.c` and `main.c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, separate definitions from declarations:

logic.h:

```
#ifndef _LOGIC_H_
#define _LOGIC_H_

/* Define BIT as before */

int adder(int O1, int O2,  BIT carryIn, BIT *carryOut);
BIT full_adder(BIT A, BIT B, BIT Ci, BIT *Co);


#endif
```

logic.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "logic.h"

int adder(int O1, int O2,  BIT carryIn, BIT *carryOut){
  printf("in adder");
  return 0x0;
}

BIT full_adder(BIT A, BIT B, BIT Ci, BIT *Co){
  BIT S = FALSE;
  //implementation of if else's based on Truth Table
  if((A==FALSE)&&(B==FALSE)&&(Ci==FALSE)){
    S=FALSE;
    *Co = FALSE;
  }

  return S;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "logic.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  /* Do your stuff */
  return 0;
}
```

Now things are where they should be and your `logic.h` supplies the needed information to the compiler.

Your `makefile` should not need any fancy stuff with only these three files.

This needs to be done via the `makefile`:

```
gcc -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -c -o logic.o logic.c
gcc -o main main.o logic.o
```

(The logical problems that you have in your `full_adder` are left for your to solve...)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen linkers not-find/find functions depending on the order of the object files.
In your makefile you may want to try changing the order:

```
C_OBJS      = logic.o main.o
```

> I declare the function in the top of both logic.c and main.c.

The function prototype

```
BIT full_adder(BIT A, BIT B, BIT Ci, BIT *Co);
```

should only occur once, in logic.h.

The error you are getting is from the linker.

You may want to just try and compile/link it outside the Makefile:

```
gcc -c logic.c
gcc -o main main.c logic.o
```